# パネルデータの同一IDの標本の絞り込み

Tags: r, tidyverse, dplyr

[パネルデータにおけるIDごとの抽出](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/27140/%E3%83%91%E3%83%8D%E3%83%AB%E3%83%87%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E3%81%AB%E3%81%8A%E3%81%91%E3%82%8Bid%E3%81%94%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AE%E6%8A%BD%E5%87%BA/27359#27359)
の続きです。
同じIDの最新データのみを抽出したいです。
具体的には

```
ID,PANEL,Q1,Q3,Q6,Q8,Q11,Q13,Q16,Q18,Q33,Q34,Q128,Q137,Q299
50,9,1,39,NA,13,NA,NA,NA,NA,5,0,90,90,0
50,10,1,40,2,14,3,13,8,69,7,0,84,84,0
50,11,1,16,2,15,3,12,8,68,9,0,100,100,0
51,7,1,38,2,13,3,12,NA,NA,4,3,0,0,0
51,8,1,39,2,14,3,13,NA,NA,7,0,36,36,0
51,9,1,40,2,15,NA,NA,NA,NA,6,0,59,59,0
51,10,1,41,2,16,3,15,NA,NA,7,0,86,86,0
51,11,1,42,2,17,3,16,NA,NA,6,0,80,80,0
52,7,1,40,2,13,3,7,NA,NA,0,0,0,0,0
52,8,1,41,2,14,3,8,NA,NA,0,0,0,0,0
53,7,1,34,2,5,3,5,8,59,0,0,0,0,0
53,8,1,35,2,6,3,6,8,60,4,0,0,0,0
```

を

```
ID,PANEL,Q1,Q3,Q6,Q8,Q11,Q13,Q16,Q18,Q33,Q34,Q128,Q137,Q299
50,11,1,16,2,15,3,12,8,68,9,0,100,100,0
51,11,1,42,2,17,3,16,NA,NA,6,0,80,80,0
52,8,1,41,2,14,3,8,NA,NA,0,0,0,0,0
53,8,1,35,2,6,3,6,8,60,4,0,0,0,0
```

としたいと考えています。(最新のデータのみを抽出）
PANELのところが第何回調査ということです。
行の抽出なのでdplyrのfilterを使いたいですがID内でのPANELの最大値の抽出の仕方がわからないです。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24237399/how-to-select-the-rows-with-maximum-values-in-each-group-with-dplyr
を参考に data %>%  group_by(ID) %>%  filter(PANEL=max(PANEL))
とやってもうまくいかないです。
エラーメッセージはError: filter condition does not evaluate to a logical vector. です。
よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: `filter(PANEL=max(PANEL))` ではなく、`filter(PANEL==max(PANEL))` とするのではないでしょうか。

Comment: その可能性が大きいですね…明日試してみます。

Comment: == に変えたら無事成功しました。単純なミスで情けないです。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

一度、欲しい形のIDとPANELのセットだけを含むテーブルを作成し、
それに結合してはどうでしょうか？

```
master <- data %>% group_by(ID) %>% dplyr::summarise(PANEL = max(PANEL))
dplyr::left_join(master, data, by = c("ID", "PANEL"))
```